# R: pixiedust - how to add a thousands separator to numbers?

Tags: r, formatting, pixiedust-r

In the pixiedust documentation I read that all columns in a dust object are characters. If I have numbers like 1000, 2300 etc., how can I format them with a thousands separator to like 1'000 and 2'300 etc.?

Comment: `formatC(as.numeric(c("1000", "2300")), big.mark = "'")` or just `formatC(c(1000, 2300), big.mark = "'")` if we talking real numbers.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While all of the columns are forced to character, in the deep caverns of `pixiedust`, it retains some knowledge about what each column was originally, so you can still apply functions.  You just have to be a little sneaky about it (so far, this is one of the weak spots of `pixiedust`, but I think it was an unavoidable tradeoff).  Just wrap the function in `quote` and pass it to the `fn` sprinkle.

```
library(pixiedust)
DF <- data.frame(x1 = c(1000, 2000, 2300, 2400),
                 x2 = LETTERS[1:4])

dust(DF) %>%
  sprinkle(cols = "x1", 
           fn = quote(formatC(value, big.mark = "'")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works well on small numbers. One little issue is that the example displays (even cuts) longer numbers in e.g. 1.18e+05 format. Can I make the column somehow broader to show the whole number e.g. 118'006?

Comment: Look around the options in `?formatC`.  if you add `digits=6` you get what you want.  What you're bumping into is the default formatting of numeric values in R.